# Export a openvz (not kvm) VM to XEN (directly o via vmware or similar)

Tags: virtualization, xen

Is there a way to export a openvz VM from proxmox to xen?

Tkz

Answer (score 0):

Not one-to-one, but you basically just copy files over and adjust what's needed. Also, you want this question on serverfault instead.